# Splitting a line into two

Tags: normal-mode

We can make from two lines a single with `J`. It looks as the following:

```
line 1
line 2
```

after `J` pressed on line 1 we've got this:

```
line 1 line 2
```

But is there a combination which what do the opposite (not `u`)? I mean to split

```
line 1 line 2
      ^
   cursor
```

in

```
line 1
line 2
```

`i<ENTER><ESC>` is too messy. Is there a one button shortcut for this in vim already?

Comment: Assuming you want to replace the space: `r<cr>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, vim doesn't have a command for this. But vim is also all about customization. Easy enough to make your own mapping!

```
nnoremap s i<CR><Esc>
```

Comment: Got it, thank you. Anyway, I don't think using `s` is a good choice, because biult-in `s` is very convenient.

Comment: You're welcome to bind it to whatever you want. :) Just chose `s` originally because split is a good mnemonic.

Answer (score 31):

For your specific case, when you have a space, that you also like to get rid of, I usually use <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I found the following quite easy with just normal commands:

I find the space just before the word(s) I want to bring down with `f <spacebar>`, I cycle through them with `;` and `,` and then I type `r <Enter>`. If I need to split again I just keep cycling through spaces as said above and repeat the process.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found to split lines in Vim is the normal mode command `gq` (type both letters in quick succession in normal or visual mode).

In visual mode, it will split whatever is selected, in normal mode, you follow `gq` with a motion.

For example, `gql` will split one line to the currently set width. To set the width of the split lines to be different from your current setting, you can use `:set textwidth=n`, where `n` is the number of characters you want in a line, e.g., `10` and change back to your normal width when you're done.

Got this information from a Youtube [video](https://youtu.be/MA9WFO_WUOM) by Kholidfu that shows how to join and split lines in normal mode using a motion.